# Improving connectivity to a remote address?

Tags: networking

Main reason for this post is pure curiosity.

I have an online application that I use often, the basic idea is multiple users(10 to be exact) connect to a server and communicate by sending packets to the server and receiving packets from that server.

I managed to get the remote IP address for that server.

Is there a way to improve connection delay (ping time) by prioritizing connection to that specific IP ?

Are there any other ways to reduce ping time ?

My connection and the server are very stable and the connection is good.

Main cause for the problem is distance from the server is huge.

I am using windows 10 in case I missed anything ask me and I will answer.

Comment: Is the server under your control?  Can you modify settings or code there?  If ten people have to use the returned data, you could get the data once, store it in a local (nearby) server... rebroadcast if from there.  What have you tried?

Comment: What are the results of your [ping and trace route tests?](http://tools.pingdom.com/ping/)

Comment: oops. Well that was dumb.  Pingdom performs the test from their servers (in Sweden), not from your own location.  Try `ping` and `tracert` from your command line interpreter (command window...)

Comment: Do you mean prioritizing one client among the 10 clients connected, or prioritizing the server among other network activities on the client side?

Comment: This guy has 1 point, and has failed to comment after two hours.  My guess is we're talking about an online game server, and he wants to be faster than his friends.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your running processes via a tool like Task Manager to make sure that there isn't another running program that is hogging your connection?

Might also be worth plugging in directly to your router via an ethernet cable so as to more directly connect to the remote address.